# The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement

Tags: mysql, hibernate-criteria

I am facing strange hibernate issue while using select query from read-only database.

```
SQL Error: 1290, SQLState: HY000
The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Our requirement is to run select query from read-only database instead of master database.

Query: `SELECT x FROM <table_name> x WHERE x.deleted = false AND x.<column_name> = 'value'.`

Remediation we tried :

1. check logs using show_sql=true, we didn't get any intermediate operations like insert, delete or update.
2. check @@read_only flag in replica db and it has value 1.

Comment: Check the user access GRANT on the mysql server

Comment: Are you sure you aren't running that query with the `FOR UPDATE` locking option? A locking read query will cause that error on a read-only MySQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the MySQL [SHOW VARIABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-variables.html) command to verify whether your MySQL server is running in *read-only* mode:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%read_only%';
```

If any of the returned variable values is `ON` instead of `OFF`, you can set it to `OFF` with the following, replacing *variable_name* with the applicable variable (e.g., *read_only*):

```
SET GLOBAL variable_name = 'OFF';
```

Then try your query again.

Note that setting global system variables [may require](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html#set-variable-system-variables) the [super](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege.